# How to get the height of the FloatingSearchBar widget?

Tags: flutter, get, widget, height, padding

Please, I want to get the height of the bar of FloatingSearchBar widget so I can adjust the top padding of the next widget to not go under the FloatingSearchBar!

for exemple this next image from my app :
[Image from my APP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCM4b.png)

The form widget is after the FloatingSearchBar and not under it because I use a padding with a fixed chosen value!

I used this code

```
final fsb = FloatingSearchBar.of(context);
print(fsb);
```

But when I print "fsb" I get "null" value !!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: anyone can help ?